# How to construct single JSON where column1 is property name and column2 is value

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server 2016 +, how can i convert a table looking like this:

```
+---------+----------+
|   Kee   |   Val    |
+---------+----------+
| aaaaaa  | 11111111 |
| bbbbbbb |  2222222 |
+---------+----------+
```

into an object looking like this:

```
{
  "aaaaaa": "11111111",
  "bbbbbbb": "2222222"
}
```

This is what I've tried:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    Kee VARCHAR(100),
    Val VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO #tmp
(
    Kee,
    Val
)
VALUES
('aaaaaa', '11111111'),
('bbbbbbb', '2222222')


SELECT t.Kee,
       t.Val
FROM #tmp AS t
FOR JSON AUTO
DROP TABLE #tmp
```

But it gives:

```
[
  {
    "Kee": "aaaaaa",
    "Val": "11111111"
  },
  {
    "Kee": "bbbbbbb",
    "Val": "2222222"
  }
]
```

Comment: What you're asking for is not valid JSON.

Comment: @JAAulde yikes, typo, fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server's Json support is not that flexible.
You will have to manually construct that json, but it's quite simple using basic string concatenation techniques.

Prior to 2017 version use `for xml path` with `stuff`:

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (
        SELECT '","'+ t.Kee +'":"'+ t.Val
        FROM #tmp AS t
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '{') + '}' As JsonResult
```

In 2017 SQL Server finally introduced a built-in string_agg function, making the code required to get that result much simpler:

```
SELECT '{"' + STRING_AGG(t.Kee +'":"'+ t.Val, '","') +'"}'
FROM #tmp As t
```

Result (in both cases):

```
{"aaaaaa":"11111111","bbbbbbb":"2222222"}
```

Comment: What you have produced _is_ what the OP asked for, but is _not_ valid JSON.

Comment: The structure, `["key":"value"]`, is not JSON. `{"key":"value"}` **is** JSON

Comment: @JAAulde You are correct - but that, as you wrote, what the OP has asked for. An easy change in the code will provide a valid json, if that's needed. (simply change the `[` to `{` and `]`  to `}`.)

Comment: Guys, sorry i mis-typed my output JSON `{"aaaaaa":"11111111","bbbbbbb":"2222222"}` is what Im looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @JAAulde after the OP have edited the question, I've reedited the answer.

Comment: This does get the job done in this example, thanks for pointing me towards the `STRING_AGG()` function.

Comment: Glad to help :-)